# Many syntax and permissions errors on postgres sql dump import

Tags: postgresql, import

I am trying to import a `.sql` database dump into my postgres `9.6.1`. I've tried in command line as well as the Postico GUI but get a ton of errors (like thousands of lines of errors) on import.

The SQL dump is from a coworker running postgres `9.4.5` and the SQL looks valid.

My Postgres Version:

> PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin, compiled by
>   i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc.
>   build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00), 64-bit

I've tried the following imports:

`psql -U postgres dbname < ~/Desktop/dbname_local_db_20161122.sql`

Then logging in and trying it:

`psql -U postgres dbname`

`dbname=# \i ~/Desktop/dbname_local_db_20161122.sql`

**Errors: (there are way more than this)**

```
Password for user postgres: 
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
CREATE EXTENSION
COMMENT
ERROR:  schema "public" does not exist
ERROR:  extension "citext" does not exist
ERROR:  schema "public" does not exist
ERROR:  extension "pg_trgm" does not exist
SET
ERROR:  function "add_session_metric" already exists with same argument types
ERROR:  role "myrole" does not exist
ERROR:  function "session_metrics_partition_creation" already exists with same argument types
ERROR:  role "myrole" does not exist
ERROR:  function "session_metrics_partition_function" already exists with same argument types
ERROR:  role "myrole" does not exist
SET
SET
ERROR:  permission denied to create "pg_catalog.messages"
DETAIL:  System catalog modifications are currently disallowed.
ERROR:  relation "messages" does not exist
ERROR:  permission denied to create "pg_catalog.Message_id_seq"
DETAIL:  System catalog modifications are currently disallowed.
ERROR:  relation "Message_id_seq" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "Message_id_seq" does not exist
ERROR:  permission denied to create "pg_catalog.sessions_users"

invalid command \N
invalid command \N
invalid command \N
invalid command \N
invalid command \N
invalid command \.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2"
LINE 1: 2 hello 3 1 2015-11-12 09:25:14.646-07 2015-11-12 09:25:14.64...
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: 1 
        ^
ERROR:  relation "external_session_info_sessions" does not exist
invalid command \.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2528"
LINE 1: 2528 1
        ^
invalid command \.
ERROR:  relation "feedback_id_seq" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('feedback_id_seq', 1, false);
```

Like I said, the SQL file looks valid. I've checked for compatibility issues from `9.4.5` to `9.6.1` but don't see any.

I do see `PERMISSION DENIED` but I am running the command as user `postgres` which has super user permissions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, the recommended way is to use `pg_dump` from the higher (target) database version to create the dump, because that version of `pg_dump` knows about incompatible changes that happened since and can create a dump that will restore correctly.

Some of the errors are normal if you restore a dump into a database that already has objects with the same names in it; often that is a sign that the dump should actually have been created with `pg_dump -C` to include a `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

However, your SQL script seems seriously messed up, and I doubt that it is an unmodified dump of a 9.4.5 database.

`pg_dump` will never dump any objects in `pg_catalog`. This schema can only contain system objects which are not included in a dump (they are created by `CREATE DATABASE`), and as you have seen, not even a superuser may create an object in that schema (unless [`allow_system_table_mods`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-developer.html#GUC-ALLOW-SYSTEM-TABLE-MODS) is `on`, which it really shouldn't be).